# BigQuery Slot Usage and Billing across Projects

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a question on how BigQuery handles slot allocation when running queries from one  project that select data from tables in another project.

Let's assume the following scenario.

I have project A which is associated with billing account A
I have project B which is associated with billing account B
I have user C

User C has been granted permissions to query data in project A and project B.

User C logs on and selects project B from the dropdown at the top.
User C then runs a query against project A

From which project will the resources/slots be allocated? Project A or project B?
Which project will be billed? Project A or project B?

Comment: Whichever project is active is the one that is used/billed. So, in this case project B is the answer for both.

Comment: Slot allocation is per billing account, though - not per project. Especially relevant if you have a flat rate.

Comment: @MartinWeitzmann are you sure about this? I can see why this would be the case for flate rate. However, my understanding is that slot allocations happens per project in on-demand.

Comment: @UliBethke Hello, have you found an answer about whether for on-demand model 2000 slot limit is per project or per billing project?:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From which project will the resources/slots be allocated?

Project B

> Which project will be billed?

Project B

Simple way of checking which project is/was "active" for specific query is to open `Details Tab` and check `Job ID` - the structure is `project:location.id`. So `project` part will tell you which project is/was active for the given query

Comment: So in theory projects could be used to isolate different types of queries, users, workloads from each other, e.g. one project for the marketing department with 2000 compute slots and one for the sales department with 2000 compute slots. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: That's exactly the case! Read more about billing and slots - you can even set priorities, inheritance, hierarchies and stuff like this to fine tune your consumption of slots and budget

Comment: you might be interested in checking [Data Warehousing With BigQuery: Best Practices (Cloud Next '19)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZVgt1-LfWW4&feature=youtu.be&t=1377) - it is about BigQuery Slots Reservation

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation you will be billed under the billing attached to Project B and the slot usage will be in Project B as well. Regardless whether a view in project B is selecting from a table in project A as long as project B is the active project then you will be billed under the billing attached to project B.

[BigQuery Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#how_charges_are_billed)

Comment: And you have a maximum of 2,000 slots "per project" for on-demand pricing https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#queries