# BigQuery Slot Usage On-Demand

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

We are using BigQuery On-Demand pricing model and our slot consumption has grown significantly lately. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55848562/bigquery-slot-usage-and-billing-across-projects) helped me with understading cross-project query billing. But I am still not sure, whether we have 2000 slot quota per project or per billing account. If I create new project **Project_2** and query from it my resources in the existing project **Project_1**, will it use 2000 slot quota from **Project_2**, **without** using slot quota from **Project_1**? Giving me **4000 slots total** (2000 per project).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#query_jobs) pretty clear:

[image]